# How to pass multiple parameter in ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I want to pass multiple parameter with ajax call.

Ajax function:--

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'Home/SaveData',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"data" : data + "id" : 1}, //<-- I want to send data and id  
            dataType: "application/JSON",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("Success");


            },
            error: function (result) {
                data.str = null;
                alert("Error");


            },
        });

    }
```

-----Controller

[HttpPost] 
        public JsonResult SaveData(string data,int id)
        {
            foreach (string s in data.Split(','))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                {
                    //Perform your opeartion here
                }
            }

```
        return Json("");


    }
```

Regards,
vinit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using $.ajax you can see that it uses javascript objects to handle everything.
The data property you set wants another javascript object.

```
 data:{data:data, id:id}

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://example.url.tosendto",
 data: { data: data, id: id} // Data property of the object wants another javascript object
 })
 .done(function( msg ) {
 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

When setting up your data as a JSON object you need to use a comma instead of a plus to make it a valid object of key value pairs:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'Home/SaveData', 
type: 'POST',
data: {"data" : data, "id" : 1},
dataType: "application/JSON", success: function (result) { alert("Success");    
        },
        error: function (result) {
            data.str = null;
            alert("Error");
        },
    });
}
```

This should now bind to your two action parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
data: "data=" + data + "&id=1",
```

Comment: No!  Your data isn't being encoded properly here.  Plus, you have a syntax error.